# Propositional Logic Proof, for proving $\overline{M}$

Tags: predicate-logic, solution-verification

I'm having some difficulty proving $\overline{M}$

H1: $P \wedge Q$

H2: $P \rightarrow \overline{Q \wedge S}$

H3: $G \rightarrow S$

H4: $M \wedge P \rightarrow G$

So far, I've only done a few steps, but am stuck. I'm trying to apply the rules of inference, but I'm not totally sure where to go.

H1: $P \wedge Q$

S1: $P$ : Simplification of H1

H2: $P \rightarrow \overline{Q \wedge S}$

S2: $P \rightarrow \overline{Q} \vee \overline{S}$ : De Morgan's Law of H2

H3: $G \rightarrow S$

S3: $P \rightarrow G$ by resolution of S2 and H3 (is this possible?)

H4: $M \wedge P \rightarrow G$

S5: ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to express this in terms of the formal logic rules you're allowed to use, but the reasoning is clear.

We know from $H_1$ that $P$ is true, so $H_2$ tells us that at least one of $Q$ or $S$ must be false.  But we also know from $H_1$ that $Q$ is true, so $S$ must be false.

$H_3$ tells us that $G \rightarrow S$, but we already know that $S$ is false, so $G$ must also be false.

Similarly, $H_4$ tells us that $M \land P \rightarrow G$, but we already know that $G$ is false, so $M \land P$ also must be false.  We also know from $H_1$ that $P$ is true, so that means $M$ must be false, so $\overline{M}$ must be true.